# How to write arabic string value to Firedac Memtable TStringField?

Tags: delphi, arabic, firedac, arabic-support, fdmemtable

I use Delphi 11.3 with Firedac database components.

I want to set Firedac Memtable TStringField value with arabic text. The value comes from a service method as json like at below.

```
            "sticker": {
                "applicationMethod": "يعطى عن طريق الفم ولايجب لمضغها",
                "caution": "يجب عدم استخدام تحت سن 18. إذا استمرت الشكوى بعد 14 يوما فيرجى استشارة مع الطبيب",
                "description": "يستخدم في البواسير الناتج عن الشكوى من دوالي وريدية",
                "effectOnDriver": "",
                "medicationTime": "",
                "riskCaution": "",
                "storageCondition": ""
            }
```

When I set the field value with arabic one, the value show every character as "?". How can I solve this problem. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You can`t hold this symbols in TStringField.

Change datatype of string fields in FieldDefs property of TFDMemTable from ftString into ftWideString.

If you create some TStringField in desingTime - delete it and recreate as TWideStringField and all will works corectly.